# OS X Yosemite - Adding a Printer - UI Vs lpadmin

Tags: macos, printing

My problem is that when I add a printer using the Printers and Scanners UI printing works, when I add the same printer using lpadmin it doesn't.

To Add it through the UI I did the following:

From Printers and Scanners I selected the IP tab.
Address: 10.20.30.40, Protocol HP Jetdirect - Socket, Queue left blank, Name: TEST_01, Location "Top Floor", Use -> Select software -> HP LaserJet P3010 Series

After doing this, the Printer works as expected.

This is a (segment from a) script containing my lpadmin command that doesn't work

```
SUBNET=socket://10.20.30.
TEST_01=40
PPD_DIR=/Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources
TEST_01_PPD="hp LaserJet P3010 Series.gz"

lpadmin -E -p TEST_01 -v $SUBNET$TEST_01 -P "$PPD_DIR/$TEST_01_PPD" -D "TEST_01" -L "Top Floor"
```

The printer appears correctly in the UI but shows as paused.

I did find a message in system.log that may or may not be relevant - I was using Notes to test the printer:

```
Notes[502]: Failed to connect (_delegate) outlet from (com_hp_psdriver_19_11_0_PDEView) to (com_hp_psdriver_19_11_0_PDEAccountingController): missing setter or instance variable
Notes[2198]: Printing failed because PMSessionEndDocumentNoDialog() returned -30871.
```

The reason I want to use a script is that there are 20 printers to add on each of 30 new Macs. The actual script uses a series of arrays with lpadmin in a for loop.  Everything I have read says it should work.  What am I missing?

Comment: If this is a `bash` script, try changing the first line to `#!/bin/bash -xv` and running it again - it will show you all the steps and expansions it is making as it does them.

Comment: I had forgotten about the -xv.  I found an element missing from one of the arrays but it hasn't shown up anything to show how to my original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `-E` specified *before* the printer name enables encryption, whereas specified *after* it `E`nables the printer - effectively "unpausing" it. Madness- I know!

[Mad Apple Documentation - see second sentence](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/lpadmin.8.html)

I think you want:

```
lpadmin -p TEST_01 -v $SUBNET$TEST_01 -P "$PPD_DIR/$TEST_01_PPD" -D "TEST_01" -L "Top Floor" -E
```

Comment: Excellent! :-) :-) :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct answer, but I can suggest an alternate approach: set up all 20 printers by hand on one computer, then copy the /etc/cups directory from that one to the other 29.

Comment: I'm going to have a look through and see what gets modified in etc/cups and see if I can spot any differences between the two setups. I'll do the directory copy as a last resort if I don't find anything.

Comment: I've noticed that the UI updates different files to lpadmin; lpadmin only changes cupsd.conf, the UI only changes printers.conf. They both add a file to the ppd directory.  I have no idea about the significance of this.